# ndc (nested diagnostic context) in LARAVEL - is it possible?

Tags: laravel, ndc

In log4net you can add NDC to filter all the logs in a specific context.  for example per session,request,cli command ext.
its a basically another field in the log that has random string, and the string is share between the contexts from abobe.
When you search for this string you can see the entire request logs.

is it possible in laravel?
Thanks